# Running Visual Studio Load Test in TFS 2015 locally

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, performance-testing, load-testing, tfs-2015

I have configured a load test using VS 2013 ultimate to performance test a REST Api. We use TFS 2015 for source control and CI. Tests are pointing to a local (with in company's intranet) REST service endpoint. I want these test to run against every build and configured a build definition in TFS. TFS provides a build step called "Cloud-based Load Test" and thats is not going to help me as I am not planning to run tests on the cloud.  what is the best approach to run `*.loadtest`
files ? Has anyone done this ? Is command line my only option ?

Comment: You may want to think again before rejecting "cloud" testing. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/09/27/run-cloud-based-load-tests-using-your-own-machines-a-k-a-bring-your-own-subscription/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command line is the only option. You need to install VS/mstest on your build agent machine, then add a `Command Line` task in your build definition. In this task, specify the mstest tool path and add agrument `/TestContainer:LoadTest1.loadtest` to run the loadtest:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint, What sort of a approach you would take to publish test results. For example , At the end of the perf test run, I have a .trx file. Is there a build template that can used to display test results graphically just like you run your tests using Visual Studio in TFS 2015 ?

Comment: There is no default way to display the test results graphically. You would need to develop your own extension to show the test result: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/samples-overview